# simulate onChange event to fire on HTML input box

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have jQuery that uses the change event from a selection box to update a input box on the form.  I need the input box to fire it's change event when I update it's value.

This link on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shows a way to simulate the click event.  Is there a technique I can use to simulate a change event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$('#input-id').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **trigger `change` event handler**. You can simply call it like that:

```
jQuery('#my_field').change();
```

which is a shortcut to:

```
jQuery('#my_field').trigger('change');
```

See more on the [documentation of `.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) (its third, attribute-less variation).

Answer (score 0):

This should theoretically do it:

```
<input id="textinput" value="somevalue" name="somename" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomethingOnInputChange(e) {
        console.log('input on change');
    }

    $('#textinput').bind('change', doSomethingOnInputChange);


    $('#textinput').trigger('change');
</script>
```

It binds an event handler to a custom 'change' event and then fires the event.

Answer (score 0):

There are several good jQuery based answers already (though you didn't use a jQuery tag) but there's another approach that can work for you if you're binding the change event to call a function.

Say you've already bound the change event to  the `doSomethingOnInputChange` function as in Vlad's answer...

Rather than simulating an event by triggering 'change' you can directly call `doSomethingOnInputChange` - that is, instead of doing:

```
$('#textinput').trigger('change')
```

your javascript just makes a call to the same function that gets called anyway when you trigger the event:

```
doSomethingOnInputChange( ... );
```

You may or may not want to pass the `#textinput` DOM element as a parameter in a direct call, or an event parameter (but providing your own event parameter makes this approach hardly worthwhile) -- those depend on what you need to do in the function.